# Request.QueryString and OutputCache in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with Request.QueryString that returns a null value. I think that is from OutputCache

I have in Default.aspx (with master file)

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="button" %>

<script runat="server">
   protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
      TimeMsg.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString( "G" );
      string v = Request.QueryString["button"];
      PageName.Text = v;
   }
</script>

<form method="get" action="Default.aspx">
   <h5>Click a button</h5>
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="One" />
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="Two" />
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="Three" />
   </form>



   <p>Page generated at : <asp:Label ID="TimeMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
   <p>Page name : <asp:Label ID="PageName" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
```

I don't write anymore the `<asp:Content ID='' ...></asp>` tag.

When I press one of button, the PageName returns empty that I checked the `v` variable with Debugger and I see that it returns null.

Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `Request.QueryString["button"];` to `Request.Form["button"];` you will get the expected output. This is probably because of `Form` in your master page.

Comment: Yeah but the get string will not appear in URL...it must be like as `localhost/Default.aspx?buttonvalue=One` or something like that

Comment: yeah bcoz its treating it as post instead of get

Comment: you can try changing the method to get fro form in your masterpage

Comment: Yeah, it works but in URL I have `?ViewState=%......%_&button=One`. How do I eliminate `ViewState` ? or it is not possible ? I tried to set to form (from master page) `enablestateview = 'false'` but it appears as huge URL content

Comment: nope disable viewstate wont help, you need to use javascript to remove this before submitting the form